# Change the number of home screen panels in Android

Tags: 2.2-froyo, home-screen, launcher, htc-wildfire-s

A phone user manual (HTC Wildfire S. **Android 2.2**) says

> 'Home screen has seven panels that you can customise'.

The system settings do not contain an option to modify the number of panels.

I was searching for this on the web and was not able to find any solution that does not involve third-party applications.

If this requires programming, please, move the question to StackOverflow and respond with detail.

Comment: You'll need to at least provide the phone model and Android version. The ability to change the number of home screens varies greatly between different vendors and versions.

Comment: on my galexy s2 I press home, home (I am now on home screen), menu, edit, +

Comment: typically, pressing the settings button while looking at your home screen, then pressing edit screens brings up the menu that allows you to add and remove screens.

Comment: Install ADW Launcher, LauncherPro or Go Launcher EX which provide such options...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't want use 3rd party apps:

This requires decent computer skills and a [rooted phone](http://droidlessons.com/what-is-rooting-on-android-the-advantages-and-disadvantages/), but here are the steps for android 2.3 Gingerbread.

1. Copy /system/home.apk from your phone to pc.
2. Decompile home.apk using apktool.
3. Goto [decompiled folder]/res/values/integer.xml
4. Change `<integer name="number_of_desktop_panes">5</integer>`, to 7 or whatever you want.
5. Save it,and compile the apk using apktool.
6. Copy it back to phone i.e to /system,change its permissions to -rw-r-r.

Comment: Editing an XML file is hardly considered compiling.

Comment: after editing XML,you are going to compile back the "apk".

Comment: That's not programming either.

Comment: I do not see a file manager in the phone and when I mount it I do not access /system/ ?

Comment: Phone needs to rooted.Then you access /system.

Comment: It's probably a good idea not too set this too high either, taking memory and performance into account.

Answer (score 4):

When you are on home screen, press the *Menu* button, then *Edit* submenu and you will have all the panels displayed. A long press on one of it will select a panel, then you will be able to move it into the trash.

You will be able to reduce the number of panels but no way to have more than 7 panels on a SGS2.

Comment: There is no Edit submenu. I press home button twice and see a list of panels (like thumbnails) on the screen. I can drag and re-arrange them, but I do not see how to remove.

Answer (score 4):

> Home screen has seven panels that you can customize.

You can't change the number of home screen *panels*. The quoted part simply means that there are seven panels that can be customized to your liking e.g: add shortcuts, widgets.

If you want to decrease that simply switch to a 3rd party launcher like [Go launcher Ex](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex).