# Reduce number of home screens to 1

Tags: home-screen, 4.3-jelly-bean

The solution from this page:

https://android.stackexchange.com/a/30484/43575

doesn't seem to work in Android 4.3

There's no home.apk. I found a Launcher2.apk file but it doesn't contain any integer.xml file.

Does anyone know how to do it in 4.3 too?

Comment: Sounds like too much effort to me.  Why not just use another launcher, such as Nova Launcher, which lets you edit it more simply?